# Configuring/installing either AX1000m Ethernet adapter or an realtek rtl8812au for kali linux

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, debian, kali-linux

I am having problems connecting to my network at home with Kali-Linux or my new Ubuntu that i dual installed on my mac-book-pro 2012 I bought a "real-tek" rtl8812AU WiFi driver which i can get read on Kali-Linux by the command "lsusb" it reads phy0 and then the driver info i don't know what the problem is and all the things i have read or fixes people are already connected to the internet...

Comment: What have you tried? I've found that drivers for newer AC gear sometimes lag and you often have to compile your own drivers. The USB ethernet adaptor *should* work out of the box. That said, compiling your own drivers is a useful, fundamental skill one might want to work out *before* diving into being a hacker.